# ZPL code works but skips 8 labels every time I print one

Tags: android, zebra-printers, zpl

I have a label I am printing via the SDK on android over bluetooth.  The format is ZPL.  There's a 3 letter code and a 10 digit number under it. ZQ520 printer, latest SDK.

I've tried setting length with ^LL and ~JL, did not help, sometimes did not print.

```
^XA
^CF0,130
^FO300,40^FDABC^FS
^CF0,40
^FO250,140^FD1234567890^FS
^XZ
```

I want to print 1 label at a time, not 1 label and 8 blank labels.  Labels appear to be about .75" by 1.5" and have the black bar between labels on the back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this happen on other models of Zebra printers. Solution was to calibrate the media.

Here is a link to the detail for how to do it on your printer:

https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/Calibrating-Zebra-QLn-Series-Mobile-Printers?language=en_US

Comment: Sorry I should have followed up, this was the correct answer but the project got shifted to another dev.

Answer (score 1):

The link in above answer is not valid anymore (Nov 2020)

This is where I found a link for the calibration command: https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/Calibrating-Zebra-QLn-Series-Mobile-Printers?language=en_US

This actually helped my with the same issue that it printed blank labels before printing my label data